# Redux/React: why `this.props` undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My codes:

```
  render() {
    console.log( 'render, state' + Array.isArray(this.props.users) + ',' + JSON.stringify(this.props.users) );
    return (
      <section>
        <div>testing</div>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.users)}</div>
        <ul>
          {this.props.users.map( user => <li>{user.email}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </section>
    );
  }
```

Both `<div>testing</div>` and `<div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.users)}</div>` work fine (after removing `<ul>...</ul>`). But `<ul>...</ul>` did not work. the error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

**UPDATE**

The following codes work fine, `this.props.users` is an Array, and all the console logs look OK. **I just need to know why `<ul>{this.props.users.map( user => <li>{user.email}</li>)}</ul>` not work. Why `this.props.users` in `<ul>...</ul>` is undefined.**

```
  render() {
    console.log( 'render, state' + Array.isArray(this.props.users) + ',' + JSON.stringify(this.props.users) );
    return (
      <section>
        <div>testing</div>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.users)}</div>
      </section>
    );
  }
```

the console output of the above codes (only two s):

```
render, statetrue,[{"_id":"5831e6df511e","updatedAt":"removed","createdAt":"removed","email":"removed","password":"xxxx","__v":0,"role":"xxx","profile":{"firstName":"test","lastName":"tester"}},{...}, {...}]
```

**UPDATE**

My codes:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchAllUsers } from '../../actions/index';

class HomePage extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log( 'componentWillMount()' );
    this.props.fetchAllUsers();
  }

  render() {
    console.log( 'render(), ' + Array.isArray(this.props.users) + ',' + JSON.stringify(this.props.users) );
    return (
      <section>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.users)}</div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log( 'state:' + JSON.stringify(state) );// working fine, and the console.log is OK. not added to this post
    return  {
        users: state.admin.users
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchAllUsers})(HomePage);
```

console.log (some details in the User objects removed.):

```
render(), true,[{"_id":"5831","profile":{"firstName":"test","lastName":"tester"}},{"_id":"5831e874cedf511f", "profile":{"firstName":"cccc","lastName":"cc"}},{"_id":"5831120","profile":{"firstName":"cccccccc","lastName":"ccc"}}]
```

And, on the webpage, the string of `this.props.users` is shown.

**My question is why `<ul>{this.props.users.map( user => <li>{user.email}</li>)}</ul>` not work, but `<div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.users)}</div>` working fine.**

I think I already described my questions clearly. If more information needed, please tell me.

**More details**

my admin_reducer.js

```
import { FETCH_ALL_USERS } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { users:[] };

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  console.log( 'users is action.payload:'+JSON.stringify( { users:action.payload } ) );
  return Object.assign( {}, state, {users:action.payload});
  //return { ...state, users:action.payload };
}
```

my index.js

```
import adminReducer from './admin_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ...
  admin: adminReducer
});
```

export default rootReducer;

```
my action.js
export function fetchAllUsers() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get(`${API_URL}/user/all`)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_ALL_USERS,
        payload: response.data
      });
    })
    .catch(response => dispatch(errorHandler(response.data.error)))
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

why console log of `console.log(this.props.users)` is `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`?

Comment: `this.props` is not undefined at all, your question is wrong.

Comment: It cannot read property `map` of undefined. Seeing as map is called only in a single line, It refers to `this.props.users.map`, which means that `this.props.users` is either undefined, or not initialized properly as an array

Comment: @DorWeid please see my updates. Thanks

Comment: Re-read what @DorWeid said. `this.props.users` is probably not initialized to an empty array.

Comment: @BAE the code seems OK. Can you try creating a fiddle or a code snippet with the example? Or post more relevant code from your actions/reducers

Comment: In your render() do a console.log(this.props.users) - what is the output?

Comment: @AlexYoung Please see my update. If <ul></ul> codes removed, `this.props.users` is an Array of User Objects.

Comment: Array.isArray(this.props.users) is returning false.  The object is not an array.  We'll need to see the code in the parent component where the object is created and then we can help out.

Comment: @AlexYoung sorry for that `false` is the output of `Array.isArray(this.props)`. `this.props.users` is Array

Comment: We need to see proof that it's an array, though; how are you getting the users into the component?

Comment: @DaveNewton Please see my update. Thanks

Comment: Is the fetchAllUsers method you are using in your connect asynchronous?  Can you post the reducer function that handles state.admin.users please?

Comment: Still not enough information to help. in any case, you probably just need to check to see if there are users to render yet, and/or use a loading status property to determine what to render. Remember: components using asynch data fetches must be able to render appropriately before the fetch has ended.

Answer (score 1):

First of, according to [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), async requests should be made inside the `componentDidMount` method.

Secondly, to make sure that you're not trying to `map` an un-initialized array, use this:

`<ul>{(this.props.users || []).map( user => <li>{user.someProperty}</li> )}</ul>`

This should cover it in case you forgot to initialize the array for some reason.

Comment: Fixed the syntax. It wasn't really about the syntax, but about the condition for `map`

Answer (score 0):

You can call this without error..

```
JSON.stringify(this.props.users)
```

...because it just outputs "undefined"). That is valid.  However, if you try to **call a method on the undefined** that was returned, of course that fails...

```
// Following tries to call undefined.map(), which is of course wrong
this.props.users.map( user => <li>{user.email}</li>)
```

Common shorthand to address your scenario uses a "short-circuit operator" (like a quickie "if (is true)")...

```
<ul>{this.props.user && this.props.users.map( user => <li>{user.email}</li>)}</ul>
```

^^ Note the "this.props.user && ", which prevents the following this.props.user.map() from being called if this.props.user is null or undefined